# Run script when window manager loads using root owned 700 autostart file

Tags: startup, startx

One of the 3rd party proprietary GUI software I use requires typing login credentials every time I log in to my Cinnamon desktop. It does not support autologin of any kind. Therefore, I decided to automate this using xdotool.

However, for this to work script needs to store login credentials. To preserve some kind of security, I would like to restrict access to the file containing password in plaintext to root user only.

How can I autostart this script so it runs when user enters desktop session, but is not readable by user?